# how to highlight syntax using flask-flatpages

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, pygments

I recently built a website using flask, flask-flatpages, and flask-freeze and I am wondering how to highlight syntax when I use block-codes in my markdown files.

These are my installed packages:

`click (6.6)
Flask (0.11.1)
Flask-FlatPages (0.6)
Frozen-Flask (0.13)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
Markdown (2.6.7)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (9.0.1)
Pygments (2.1.3)
PyYAML (3.12)
setuptools (27.2.0)
Werkzeug (0.11.11)
wheel (0.29.0)`

and my flatpage render settings for my web looks like this:

```
def prerender_jinja(text):
    return pygmented_markdown(render_template_string(Markup(text)))

FLATPAGES_EXTENSION =['.md']
FLATPAGES_MARKDOWN_EXTENSION =['codehilite']
FLATPAGES_HTML_RENDERER = prerender_jinja
```

What else do I have to do in order to enable syntax highlighting when I convert my .md files to .html files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://flask-flatpages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works:

> To use Pygments, you need to include the style declarations separately. You can get them with pygments_style_defs():
>
> ```
> @app.route('/pygments.css')
> def pygments_css():
>     return pygments_style_defs('tango'), 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'}
> ```
>
> and in templates:
>
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('pygments_css') }}">`

Comment: I have tried this, but my code block remains style-less. Just black font.

Comment: Did you open the file directly in the browser or did you start an webserver (i.e. `cd build; python -m SimpleHTTPServer` -> open http://localhost:8000 in your browser)?

Comment: I started a webserver

Comment: Ah, okay. the solution was to have the language specified. (when I did the above style declaration, i was only getting html syntax highlighted)

I basically pasted the code in Sebastian's comment and did

    :::javascript
    block code I want to write